# How to display csv data in tabular form in Flask Python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask, read.csv

I'm making a web app using the Flask framework with python, I want to make the web able to upload csv without saving and displaying data in a table with the template I made, I've added the syntax for uploading and processing the data until it's in a table view, but after running the website it goes to the 404 not found error message, how can I fix it?
I've made a code in main.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from FlaskWebProject2 import app
import os
import pandas as pd
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

#*** Flask configuration
 
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join('staticFiles', 'uploads')

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'csv'}
 
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templateFiles', static_folder='staticFiles')

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
 
app.secret_key = 'This is your secret key to utilize session in Flask'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/upload',  methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def uploadFile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # upload file flask
        uploaded_df = request.files['uploaded-file']
 
        # Extracting uploaded data file name
        data_filename = secure_filename(uploaded_df.filename)
 
        # flask upload file to database (defined uploaded folder in static path)
        uploaded_df.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], data_filename))
 
        # Storing uploaded file path in flask session
        session['uploaded_data_file_path'] = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], data_filename)
 
        return render_template('index_upload_and_show_data_page2.html')

@app.route('/show_data')
def showData():
    # Retrieving uploaded file path from session
    data_file_path = session.get('uploaded_data_file_path', None)
 
    # read csv file in python flask (reading uploaded csv file from uploaded server location)
    uploaded_df = pd.read_csv(data_file_path)
 
    # pandas dataframe to html table flask
    uploaded_df_html = uploaded_df.to_html()
    return render_template('show_csv_data.html', data_var = uploaded_df_html)
```

I want the website can show the home page and upload, read and show csv data works properly

Answer (score 1):

If you are requesting `/upload` and getting a 404. This is natural. You have added a handler for `/upload` endpoint:

```py
@app.route('/upload',  methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def uploadFile():
    ...
```

But `uploadFile` only supports `POST` requests. When you enter `localhost/upload` into the browser, the browser sends a `GET` request to the web server. There are two solutions for you with the same result:

1. Add another `if` to `uploadFile` function and check if incoming request is `GET` and if it is, show a page(e.g. a form to upload file).
2. Write another function like `upload_file_form` exclusively for `GET` requests to show a form.

P.S.: per [PEP8](https://pep8.org/), you should use `camel_case` for function names. e.g. `upload_file` rather than `uploadFile`